# Нет возможности изменить размер формы

Tags: c#, winforms

У формы назначено свойство `FormBorderStyle="Sizable"`, но пользователь не может изменить размер формы. Само свойство мной назначено не программно. Могут ли еще быть свойства, с которыми у `FormBorderStyle` происходит конфликт?

Comment: Конкретизируйте пожалуйста какая у Вас возникла проблема и как Вы уже попытались ее решить. А то на вопрос  "Могут ли еще быть..." можете получить ответ "Могут." Подумайте насколько такой ответ будет Вам полезен.

Answer (score 0):

`SizeGripStyle`, `AutoSize` (при `AutoSizeMode`=`GrowAndShrink`), `MaximumSize` и `MinimumSize`.